# Vue-Router: Refresing(F5) current page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

When I press refresh(F5) button then my router directs me to the main page. How do I stay on the same page when the page is refreshed?

that's route, mode is 'history'

```js
const routes = [
   { path: '*', redirect: '/'  }, 
  {
    path: '/', component: template_Default, redirect: '/Login',
    children: [
      { path: 'Login', component: login_, name: 'Login' },
      { path: 'SignUp', component: signUp_, name: 'SignUp' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/Main', component: template_Home, name: 'Main', redirect: '/Main/Overview',
    children: [
      { path: 'Overview', component: overview_, name: 'Overview' },
      { path: 'Customer', component: customer_, name: 'Customer' },
      { path: 'Task', component: task_, name: 'Task' },
      { path: 'Order', component: order_, name: 'Order' },
      { path: 'Product', component: product_, name: 'Product' },
      { path: 'Setting', component: setting_, name: 'Setting' }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/ForgotPassword', component: forgotPassword_, name: 'ForgotPassword', 
    // redirect: '/ForgotPassword/GetEmail',
    // children: [
    //   { path: 'GetEmail', component: forgotPasswordGetEmail, name: 'GetEmail' },
    //   { path: 'ReSend', component: forgotPasswordReSend, name: 'ReSend' }

    // ]
  }
]
```

And my controller,

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
    const publicPages = ['/Login','/SignUp','/ForgotPassword'];
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
    const loggedIn = store.getters.isLoggedIn;
    
    if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
      return next('/Login');
    }else next();
    if(loggedIn){
      AuthController.IsOnline();
    }
    
  })
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have `{ path: '*', redirect: '/' }` as the first item in your routes array. According to the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes):

> When using asterisk routes, make sure to correctly order your routes so that asterisk ones are at the end.

This is because Vue Router searches through your list of routes in order and returns the first matching route. An asterisk is going to match any and all routes so, when you refresh the page, it returns the first route and redirects you to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but my route have no `{ path: '*', redirect: '/' }`
Here is my code.

```
export const routes = [
    {
      path:'/login',
      component: login,
      name: 'home'
    },
    {
      path:'/',
      component: mainapp,
      name: 'mainapp',
      meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            },
                children: [
            {
                path:'/dash',
                component: dashboard,
                name: 'dashboard'
            },
            {
                path:'/dept',
                component: dept,
                name: 'department'
            },
            {
                path: '/deptDetail',
                component: deptDetail,
                name: 'detail'
            },
            {
                path:'/hrd',
                component: HRD
            },
            {
                path:'/notify',
                component: notify
            },
            {
                path:'/device',
                component: device
            },
            {
                path:'/setup',
                component: setup,
                name: 'setup'
            },
            {
                path:'/scanArea',
                component: area,
            },
            {
                path:'/env',
                component: environment,
            },
            {
                path:'/record', /* debug page */
                component: record,
            },
            {
                path:'/redis', /* debug page */
                component: redis,
            },
            {
                path:'/permit',
                component: permit,
            },
            {
                path:'/app',
                component: app,
            }
        ]
    },
  ]
```